# Есть reader в содержащий строки вида Артем 5, Андрей 7, Артем 3

Tags: java

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы написать метод, который считывает эти данные и заполняет карту , где ключом будет имя, а значением соответственно значение и суммирует значения у повторяющихся ключей. Получается что в моем примере в карте должны оказать Артем 8 и Андрей 7. Я так понимаю что то можно реализовать 2-мя способами. 1) с помощью класса сканер и его методов 2) с помощью BufferedReader. вот мой код для сканера, никак не могу понять в чем проблема.

```
    Public static Map<String, Long> getsm(Reader reader) {
            Map<String, Long> res = new HashMap<>();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String key = scanner.nextLine();
                Long value = scanner.nextLong();
                if (res.containsKey(key)) {
                    res.put(key, res.get(key) + value);
                } else {
                    res.put(key, value);
                }
            }
            return res;
        }
```

Объясните плз что я тут делаю не так и по возможности направьте в правильное русло) так же буду признателен за помощь в решении с помощью BufferedReader. Всем спасибо

Comment: Думаю, вы вводите элементы в 1 строку "Максим <пробел> 3". И первый же `nextLine()` считывает всю строку. А надо только первый элемент. Замените `nextLine()` на `next()`. Ну и после `nextLong()`нужно считать конец строки

Answer (score 1):

так проще мне кажется...

```
public static Map<String, Long> getsm(Reader reader) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) list.add(scanner.next());
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Если ваш ридер - это чтение файла, то все еще проще

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fileName = "c://lines.txt";
    System.out.println(getsm(fileName));
}

private static Map<String, Long> getsm(String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        return stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    }
}
```

Ваш метод нужно откорректировать с учетом того, что я сказал в комментариях, таким образом (один из вариантов):

```
public static Map<String, Long> getsm(Reader reader) {
    Map<String, Long> res = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        for (String s : scanner.nextLine().split(", ")) {
            int index = s.indexOf(" ");
            String key = s.substring(0, index);
            Long value = Long.valueOf(s.substring(index+1, s.length()));                
            res.put(key, res.containsKey(key) ? res.get(key)+value : value);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Это немного не то, что мне нужно, т.к. reader надо перезаписать в мапу ключ/значение. И все таки мне хочется понять, как правильно доделать именно мой код, или в какой момент я ошибся.

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос. Что это за ридер? Вы читаете из файла? Даные в файле записаны именно так - Артем 5, Андрей 7, Артем 3, т.е. в одну строчку через запятую. Или запятых нет и строчек 3, или может быть есть запятые, но строчек все равно 3. А может это вообще не файл? Это влияет на решение...

Comment: хотя проблему я и так скажу... scanner.nextLine() - это забирает всю строку, т.е. Артем 5, Андрей 7, Артем 3, а не первое имя. Вы можете использовать scanner.next(), тогда в ключ попадет только Артем , однако на следующем шаге scanner.nextLong() в значение попадет "5," , поскольку после 5 нет пробела, то запятая не позволит преобразовать это в лонг и вы получите ошибку. мало, того, теперь scanner.hasNext() не работает корректно, поскольку проверяет строку. вызов  next() должен быть один в цикле, а у вас2. правильнее вызывать  nextLine(), а дальше парсить полученную строку.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за ваше участие) в условии задачи не говорится что за reader,только сказано что данные в нем в виде  Артем 5  Андрей 7 Артем 3 (все с новой строки). Удалось решить задачу с помощью вашей подсказки по поводу метода next(). Был бы признателен если бы вы еще намекнули как правильно реализовать ее с помощью bufferedReader. Большое спасибо

Comment: ну тогда читайте предыдущий комментарий...

Comment: откорректировал ответ и добавил ваш метод (исправленный)

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помог разобраться.

Comment: не за что, удачи